# invoke-sqlcmd not recognized even though SqlPs loaded

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a shell script to run a query and store the output, and I've got my script looking like this so far:

```
push-location;
import-module SqlPs;
Pop-Location;
$myData = invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\<path>\blah.sql" -serverinstance dbatest -database testdb;
$mydata | out-file C:\Users\<path>\shelloutput.csv;
remove-module sqlps;
```

It loads SqlPs fine which I can check with with `Get-Module -ListAvailable` producing this[image]

but when I do `invoke-sqlcmd` it is not recognized:[image]

Any ideas as to what else I can do?

### Edit 1

When I add the option `-Verbose` I see this error [image] saying that some files are already present. Is this error preventing me from loading the module? When I do `Get-Module` it doesn't list the SQLPS module.

### EDIT 2

Loading the 32 bit version gives me fewer errors but still errors loading files...now only 2 files are missing as opposed to 5 earlier[image]

Comment: `Get-Module -ListAvailable` shows what modules are present, not which ones were loaded.  Drop the `-ListAvailable` to show what is loaded into the current session.

Comment: @MikeShepard made an edit reflecting your comment...I tried using `import-module sqlps -force` but that didn't help

Comment: Is there a platform mismatch between PowerShell and SQL server? If you're running 32 bit SQL server, try launching the 32 bit version of PowerShell from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and see if that can load `SQLPS`.

Comment: @briantist made an edit that reflects your comment, all it does is drop the number of files already present

Answer (score 1):

I found on my system that I had in the path several sql bin references to 32 bit (Program Files (x86)) paths ahead of the 64 bit paths.  I moved all the 32 bit paths below the 64 bit paths and it cleared up the issues.